# Growing hash-of-queues beyond main memory limits

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, scalability

I have a cluster application, which is divided into a controller and a bunch of workers.  The controller runs on a dedicated host, the workers phone in over the network and get handed jobs, so far so normal.  (Basically the "[divide-and-conquer pipeline](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Divide-and-Conquer)" from the zeromq manual, with job-specific wrinkles.  That's not important right now.)

The controller's core data structure is `unordered_map<string, queue<string>>` in pseudo-C++ (the controller is actually implemented in Python, but I am open to the possibility of rewriting it in something else).  The strings in the queues define jobs, and the keys of the map are a categorization of the jobs.  The controller is seeded with a set of jobs; when a worker starts up, the controller removes one string from one of the queues and hands it out as the worker's first job.  The worker may crash during the run, in which case the job gets put back on the appropriate queue (there is an ancillary table of outstanding jobs).  If it completes the job successfully, it will send back a list of new job-strings, which the controller will sort into the appropriate queues.  Then it will pull another string off some queue and send it to the worker as its next job; usually, but not always, it will pick the same queue as the previous job for that worker.

Now, the question.  This data structure currently sits entirely in main memory, which was fine for small-scale test runs, but at full scale is eating all available RAM on the controller, all by itself.  And the controller has several other tasks to accomplish, so that's no good.

What *approach* should I take? So far, I have considered:

a) to convert this to a primarily-on-disk data structure.  It could be cached in RAM to some extent for efficiency, but jobs take tens of seconds to complete, so it's okay if it's not *that* efficient,

b) using a relational database - e.g. SQLite, (but SQL schemas are a very poor fit AFAICT),

c) using a NoSQL database with persistency support, e.g. Redis (data structure maps over trivially, but this still appears very RAM-centric to make me feel confident that the memory-hog problem will actually go away)

Concrete numbers: For a full-scale run, there will be between one and ten million keys in the hash, and less than 100 entries in each queue.  String length varies wildly but is unlikely to be more than 250-ish bytes.  So, a hypothetical (impossible) zero-overhead data structure would require 2<sup>34</sup> – 2<sup>37</sup> bytes of storage.

Comment: While the question is interesting, you may want to rephrase it. As you know, questions asking for a library are not really fit on SO! Also, some numbers would be useful. For example, how many items would you have in the hash table?

Comment: @Shahbaz I'm aware that such questions are *discouraged*, but in this case I am at a loss for either a better venue or a better way to structure the question.  Broadening it ("what should I do to this data structure so it fits better in memory and/or lives mostly on disk?" perhaps) would only make it *more* of a matter of opinion, I think.  I'll add some concrete numbers to the text.

Comment: @zack edited slightly to avoid the off topic discussion.

Comment: Make everything fixed size, oversize the hashtable and mmap() everything will cost 2-3 page faults per request. locality of reference will be bad (unless a large amount of operations is done on a few hotspots). Just do the calculations: can you stand a VM footprint of a few hundred GB? Also: doyou want persistance, even after a crash?

Comment: @zack can you clarify how many jobs you need to process in how much time (e.g. per hour)? why did you place everything in memory in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, it all boils down on *how you define efficiency* needed on part of the controller -- e.g. response times, throughput, memory consumption, disk consumption, scalability... These properties are directly or indirectly related to:

1. number of requests the controller needs to handle *per second* (throughput)
2. acceptable response times
3. future growth expectations

From your options, here's how I'd evaluate each option:

> a) to convert this to a primarily-on-disk data structure. It could be
>   cached in RAM to some extent for efficiency, but jobs take tens of
>   seconds to complete, so it's okay if it's not that efficient,

Given the current memory hog requirement, some form of persistent storage seems a reaonsable choice. Caching comes into play if there is a repeatable access pattern, say the same queue is accessed over and over again -- otherwise, caching is likely not to help.

This option makes sense if 1) you cannot find a database that maps trivially to your data structure (unlikely), 2) for some other reason you want to have your own on-disk format, e.g. you find that converting to a database is too much overhead (again, unlikely).

One alternative to databases is to look at persistent queues (e.g. using a [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/01/20/rabbitmq-backing-stores-databases-and-disks/) backing store), but I'm not sure what the per-queue or overall size limits are.

> b) using a relational database - e.g. SQLite, (but SQL schemas are a
>   very poor fit AFAICT),

As you mention, SQL is probably not a good fit for your requirements, even though you could surely map your data structure to a relational model *somehow*.

However, NoSQL databases like MongoDB or CouchDB seem much more appropriate. Either way, a database of some sort seems viable as long as they can meet your throughput requirement. Many if not most NoSQL databases are also a good choice from a scalability perspective, as they include support for [sharding](http://www.mongodb.com/learn/nosql) data across multiple machines.

> c) using a NoSQL database with persistency support, e.g. Redis (data
>   structure maps over trivially, but this still appears very RAM-centric
>   to make me feel confident that the memory-hog problem will actually go
>   away)

An in-memory database like Redis doesn't solve the memory hog problem, unless you set up a cluster of machines that each holds a part of the overall data. This makes sense only if keeping all data in-memory is needed due to **low response times** requirements. Yet, given the nature of your jobs, taking tens of seconds to complete, response times, respective to workers, hardly matter.

If you find, however, that response times do matter, Redis would be a good choice, as it handles [partitioning](http://redis.io/topics/partitioning) trivially using either client-side consistent-hashing or at the cluster level, thus also supporting scalability scenarios.

**In any case**

Before you choose a solution, be sure to clarify your requirements. You mention you want an *efficient* solution. Since efficiency can only be gauged against some set of requirements, here's the list of questions I would try to answer first:

**Requirements*

- how many jobs are expected to complete, say per minute or per hour?
- how many workers are needed to do so?

concluding from that:

- what is the expected load in requestes/per second, and
- what response times are expected on part of the controller (handing out jobs, receiving results)?

And looking into the future:

- will the workload increase, i.e. does your solution need to scale up (more jobs per time unit, more more data per job?)
- will there be a need for persistency of jobs and results, e.g. for auditing purposes?

Again, concluding from that,

- how will this influence the number of workers?
- what effect will it have on the number of requests/second on part of the controller?

With these answers, you will find yourself in a better position to choose a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into a message queue like RabbitMQ. This way it will first fill up the RAM and then use the disk. I have up to 500,000,000 objects in queues on a single server and it's just plugging away.

RabbitMQ works on Windows and Linux and has simple connectors/SDKs to about any kind of language.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/